# Eclipse java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, eclipse

I was using Eclipse and was writing a program that would read in a file and then output to another file some stats about the input file.

After working on it for a few days I got a low memory warning on my computer and saw that the output file I was working on was taking up almost 80gb on my computer. I deleted the file, but now my program can no longer write out to any file at all. I get this error

```
Editor could not be initialized.
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:137)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:121)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:569)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:190)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.filebuffers.ResourceTextFileBuffer.setDocumentContent(ResourceTextFileBuffer.java:531)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.filebuffers.ResourceTextFileBuffer.initializeFileBufferContent(ResourceTextFileBuffer.java:261)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.filebuffers.ResourceFileBuffer.create(ResourceFileBuffer.java:247)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.filebuffers.TextFileBufferManager.connect(TextFileBufferManager.java:115)
at org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextFileDocumentProvider.createFileInfo(TextFileDocumentProvider.java:563)
at org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextFileDocumentProvider.connect(TextFileDocumentProvider.java:481)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.doSetInput(AbstractTextEditor.java:4167)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.StatusTextEditor.doSetInput(StatusTextEditor.java:260)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.doSetInput(AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.java:1476)
at org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextEditor.doSetInput(TextEditor.java:153)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.lambda$1(AbstractTextEditor.java:3135)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor$$Lambda$529/1547802438.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:440)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:356)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.lambda$3(WorkbenchWindow.java:2254)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow$$Lambda$530/849256436.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:72)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2252)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.internalInit(AbstractTextEditor.java:3152)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.init(AbstractTextEditor.java:3177)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.initialize(EditorReference.java:365)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:345)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
```

I have tried all the advice that was posted in older questions here but none of them work. I have tried going to Run -> Run Configuration and changing the arguments for the VM but nothing works

Comment: Did you restart Eclipse?

Comment: If starting Eclipse with `-clean` does not help, delete `<your_workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi` to reset the perspective and close all editors.

Comment: The error you show didn't happen in your program (unless you're writing an RCP application or an eclipse plugin) - instead it's output from eclipse, and it's likely because you had that 80gb file open in eclipse. Restart eclipse